# PhoneGap Build pre-populated SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've successfully used PhoneGap Build with pre-populated SQLite DBs in the past via the https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2368 plugin. However, Adobe deprecated the use of all plugins from the PG Build repository. Thus, I've been forced to use the npm alternatives.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage is the recommended alternative to brodybits' original plugin. However, it's not compatible with PG Build due to them not honoring before_plugin_install hook.

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free and https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-legacy-build-support are the recommended PG Build solutions. These work successfully to create and save/load to a new SQLite DB. However, they do not inherently support pre-populated DBs. It seems the solution to this was to copy the directory from the www/ directory to the app's DB dir before opening the DB. This is made possible by using https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy. I've had success using this plugin, but have also experience the app initially crashing (likely due to some case where the DB was trying to be opened before it was copied..?).

It's frustrating to now have to use two plugins to do what one accomplished simply because Adobe deprecated use of its repository. Furthermore, I find it strange that the newer versions of Cordova-sqlite-storage don't support pre-populated DBs anymore when version 1.0.6 did.

I tried adding https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/tree/a97198d as the plugin source in my config.xml file. However, I can't seem to be able to specify a tag for the git repo (it only seems to pull the master version). Also, I tried adding https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/tree/a97198d as a custom plugin for PG Build and got an error for invalid url.

Does anyone know a possible solution to this? I'd really just like to be able to use the same plugin I've used for almost two years. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was the right way to add the plugin to my config.xml file